# Pronunciation of Yerushalayim

Tags: words, grammar-dikduk, etymology, yerushalayim-jerusalem

In the Tanach, the word Yerushalayim is almost always written without a yud between the lamed and mem, but pronounced as if there is a patach under the lamed and a yud following it. We find though that Malki Tzedek was called Melech Shalem in Bereshis [14:18](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t0114.htm), and the midrash in [Bereshis Rabba 56:10](https://archive.org/stream/RabbaGenesis/midrashrabbahgen027557mbp#page/n547/mode/2up) implies that that is referring to Yerushalayim. This would seem to indicate that the city's name, at one point at least, was pronounced Yerushalem, as indeed it is vowelized in Aramaic, and that at a later period it was changed to Yerushalayim, as it indeed appears in Meggilas Esther. Did the switch occur, when, and why?

Answer (score 5):

In the Chumash, we find "Malki-tzedek, king of Shalem", as well as Avraham referring to the place of Akeidat Yitzchak as "Hashem Yireh." The midrash says those names were combined, "Yireh+Shalem" -> "Yerushalayim."

Note that in Aramaic, it's pronounced "Yerushlame", which fits with how it's written Biblically -- no yud before the final mem. However in Hebrew, it's "Yerushalayim."

Comment: Why is it then that in Tanach it is still spelled without a yud? The aramaic pronunciation also would seem to indicate that the name as Yerushalem persisted *after* the combination of the names mentioned in the Midrash, which then makes the question stronger - when and why did the change occur?

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question (when and why); it just repeats what is said in the question.

Comment: @Scimonster, that's because the question was edited substantially substantively since this answer was posted.

Comment: @msh210 Oh. Now i want to take back the downvote, but it's been too long. :/

Answer (score 0):

Which Tanakh are you referencing to find the correct pronunciation of Jerusalem (ירושלם)?

We find in the Dead Sea Scrolls fragment of [Ezra 6:2] : "Yerushalem" (ירושלם). - without any niqqud [https://www.deadseascrolls.org.il/explore-the-archive/image/B-367571].

1. We also find Jerusalem pronounced "Yerushalaim" (ירוּשָׁלִַם) In the Tanakh [MT] published online @ [mechon-mamre.org]

- [2 Samuel 5:5] - "Yerushalaim" (ירוּשָׁלִַם).
- [Isaiah 2:3] - "Yerushalaim" (ירוּשָׁלִָם).
- [Ezra 1:2] - "Yerushalaim" (ירוּשָׁלִַם).

2. We also find Jerusalem pronounced "Yerushalam" and "Yerushelem" in the Tanakh [MT] edited Rabbi A.J. Rosenberg [chabad.org] :

- [2 Samuel 5:5] - "Yerushalam" (ירוּשָׁלַ֣םִ).
- [Isaiah 2:3] - "Yerushalam" (ירֽוּשָׁלִָֽם).
- [Ezra 1:2] - "Yerushalam" (ירֽוּשָׁלִַ֖ם).
- [Ezra 6:3] - "Yerushelem" (ירֽוּשְׁלֶם֙).

3. We also find Jerusalem pronounced "Yerushalaim" (ירוּשָׁלִַ֣ם) in Tanakh online @ [sefaria.org].

- [2 Samuel 5:5] - "Yerushalaim" (ירוּשָׁלִַ֣ם).
- [Isaiah 2:3] - "Yerushalaim" (ירוּשָׁלִָֽם).
- [Ezra 1:2] - "Yerushalaim" (ירוּשָׁלִַ֖ם).

Comment: Hi and welcome to MY! If the concordance is correct, the word _Jerusalem_ occurs 643 + 26 times in the _Tanakh._ Out of them only 5 times it is written using the full spelling with the _yud_ (see masorah for [Yirmiyahu 26:18](https://www.mgketer.org/mikra/13/26)). In all other (Hebrew) cases we pronounce it in a different way as the orthography would suggest, and add the _"yi"_ syllable (see [ketiv and qerei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qere_and_Ketiv)).

Comment: Welcome to MY. The question asks, in my words, 
“The name was pronounced Yerushalem and  at a later period it was changed to Yerushalayim. Did the switch occur, when, and why?” Your answer provides interesting facts (for which many thanks) but does not address the main question.