# Correct pronunciation on Jerusalem in Tehillim?

Tags: tanach, pronunciation, mesorah-tradition, yerushalayim-jerusalem

When Jersualem is חסר (no additional 'yud' at the end), in a Tehillim I have (Shai l'Moreh), it has a footnote that it should be pronounced the full way (Ye-RU-Sha-LaY-YIM) on Chapter 79 (and I think 124). Is there a tradition to pronounce it the full way always, or possibly only on those specific chapters?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pronunciation of Yerushalayim](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37559/pronunciation-of-yerushalayim)

Comment: The preexisting question assumes that the pronunciation now is with a _yod_ and asks if and when it changed from a no-_yod_ pronunciation. The present question asks whether the pronunciation now is with a _yod_. I don't see how it's a duplicate. cc @DanF

Comment: The way the nikkud is written would demand it be pronounced with a yodh every time. Hebrew diphthongs always end in a long I sound. The real question would be, what would be the pronunciation without the yodh? The only different pronunciation with the word that I'm aware of is when it is spelled qamas yodh.

Comment: The vowelization is a patach followed by a chirik, which would have the last syllable pronounced "la-im. Sounds similar to the way it's pronounced with the yod. As a matter of fact, a chirik with or without a yod is pronounced identically.

Comment: @DanF Wow, I didn't know that. Thanks.

Comment: I quickly browsed through an article that discusses the pronunciation and writing, and it MAY dispose my last comment. I'll have to hunt for it again and see if I can extract something that make sense. It used some technical language, so I have to digest it a bit more.

Answer (score -1):

[this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=EYWOAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA93&dq=orthography%20%20of%20yerushalayim%20without%20a%20yod&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAWoVChMInMjxoZ24xwIVRFc-Ch2h7w-H#v=onepage&q=orthography%20%20of%20yerushalayim%20without%20a%20yod&f=false) p. 93 mentions something about the orthography and phonology of "Yerushalayim". Summarizing some points:

- He seems to indicate that a full spelling with the 2nd *yod* would
  inidicate a tripthong making the pronunciation *ayim*. However,
  because the full spelling is rarely seen in Tanac"h, and the missing
  yod is the more common format, the author indiocates that the
  pronunciation may be more "I" or "e" sound.
- The author notes that that the missing spelling without the yod has 2 vowels, *patach* and *hirik* under the lamed. He states that based on the common pronunciation of the name *Yerushalayim* from the cases where it is spelled with a full yod, it's reasonable to support the idea of pronouncing it as *ayi* , i.e. as a tripthong even without the final yod spelling.

Comment: i've heard the second one before I think. The Tehillim I referenced in the question says "pronunce as if it had full spelling v'halan", that would seem to imply the rest of the perek but not always?

Comment: @Hugh I'm unfamiliar with the version of Tehillim that you use. I have always heard people pronounce it as "Yerushalayim" regardless of how it's spelled. That of course, doesn't prove that they are doing it correctly, though. I'm just presenting a source that states an idea that it might be pronounced Yerushalayim regardless of how it's spelled. You   may need to read more of the article to gain some context.